# Chrome New Tab Page Broken...Only get "chrome-internal://newtab/"

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-mavericks

So out of nowhere my Chrome (Version 33.0.1750.117) new tab page broke.

- I have tried disabling all extensions and it then works. I went through and re-enabled them one by one. If anything is enabled besides Google Voice Search or Hangouts, it breaks.
- I tried disabling all plugins and re-enabling one by one, and it’s broken no matter what. I tried reinstalling Chrome, still the same issue.
- It almost seems to me like I can’t access the apps page anymore, because the only extensions that cause the problem are ones that create an icon in the apps page.

In the address bar, I get "chrome-internal://newtab/" and that is it. Any idea what's going on or how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem in Google Chrome 33.0.1750.117 Windows.

The problem in my case was the IMDB extension, which I have now deactivated till they fix it.

To figure out which extension is responsible for your cause, follow these steps.

1. Create a new tab page
2. Right click in the empty page --> Inspect element.
3. Click on Resources --> Frames --> (newtab.html) --> Scripts
4. Here you'll see the script files from the extension which causes the trouble.
5. In my example the ID of the extension is: jipolnkooheenpfdecoclcohihplijco.
6. To get the name to the ID just google it. In my case its IMDB, which you can see at the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: IMDB was one of the extensions causing the problem for me too.

Comment: I found the the ESPN extension was also causing this behavior. After disabling, the new tab worked as it should.

Comment: This is really good, I assumed originally it was a bug in chrome, so glad it was just the stupid IMDB extension which I don't really use anyways

Comment: For me it was the Amazon extension, id: fbgnolfbgnobgnaiephadndggndiidff

Comment: for me it was Instagram.

Comment: Great instructions.  For me it was the Vimeo app.  Didn't need it, it was just a shortcut to their webpage.

Comment: Instagram here as well.

Answer (score 2):

From Saro Jooren on Google Product Forums [1](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/KgMBvp-yNAs%5B1-25-true%5D):

chrome-internal://newtab was a special internal URL used for old versions of the New Tab Page which is no longer supported and has been removed.
( For details see http://crbug.com/327845 - Remove unused kChromeInternalScheme "chrome-internal" )

If you are using this in a bookmark, instead change to:  chrome://newtab

If opening a New Tab page gets an error about chrome-internal://newtab, then you have an old New Tab Extension that uses this old URL that no longer works.  You can look for updated New Tab Page extensions from the Chrome webstore:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/new%20tab%20extensions

Or you can find which of your extensions is causing the problem.  Go to  chrome://extensions  and first disable all your extensions (or disable any extensions you don't recognize) and re-test.  Your New Tab page should be fine after that.  Then re-enable your extensions one-by-one to see which one was causing that error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Windows 7 (also running Chrome 33.0.1750.117m), not OSX, so this may not work for you. But hey, its worth a shot :)

I went into my extensions page and disabled everything there. I then reenabled them all one by one, like you did. The only one that was causing a problem was the one called New Tab Page that's installed by default (I assume when you install Chrome). Disabling that lets me open it up the new tab page, which apparently is back to not displaying apps unless you click the Apps button in the bookmarks bar.

I don't see that button in your address bar, though, so you might try installing the [New Tab Redirect!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna) extension (which is NOT causing me any problems), which will allow you to set the Apps page as the new tab page, should you wish. Hope it works!

Comment: Ah that helped me fix the problem. I didn't have the New Tab Page extension, but I figured out the reason I was having the problem was that two of the extensions I had must not be supporting the fact that the new tab page isn't the apps page anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As follow up i had the problem.
I disabled all extensions, and reactivated one by one trying a new tab each time to see what extension was the problem.
I found the "linkedin" extension to be my problem...

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the "Ask" tool bar and it's all back.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information on how to remove it?

Answer (score -1):

Try to uninstall all your plugins other than hangouts and voice. Then try and reinstall it. If that doesn't work, reinstall chrome.

Comment: Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: no. but it must be something with ur plugins

Comment: try: chrome://newtab instead (in your url)

Comment: can u show me a pic, also what version do u have

Comment: what do you want a picture of? Version 33.0.1750.117

Comment: ur new tab page